# map без lambda функции

Tags: python, list, map

Имеется

```
N=3
st=list(map(lambda s: ",K%d" % s,range(1,N)))#,K1,K2,K3
```

N-больше 100. 3 для краткости.
Как все это записать без **lamda** или с использованием **format** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Буквально, с использованием `format` вместо `lambda` и форматирования через `%`:

```
N = 3
print(list(map(",K{}".format, range(1,N))))
# Вывод: [',K1', ',K2']
```

Если запятая нужна для разделения элементов (начальная запятая не нужна), лучше убрать ее из строки форматирования, и использовать `join` для сборки элементов в строку с указанием запятой в качестве разделителя:

```
print(",".join(map("K{}".format, range(1,N))))
# Вывод: K1,K2
```

Еще вариация на форматирование через процент (пользуемся тем, что `",K%d" % s` эквивалентно вызову метода `__mod__`: `",K%d".__mod__(s)`)

```
print(list(map(",K%d".__mod__, range(1,N))))
```

Но в целом, сейчас (при наличии в Python format и f-строк, т.е. начиная с Python 3.6) уже нет особого смысла вообще использовать процент для форматирования. Да код с использованием функций с двойным подчеркиванием напрямую выглядит не очень хорошо.